# Thread syncronization by using bool global variable

Tags: c, multithreading

I know that this question can seem similar to already existing ones, but I couldn't find a useful suggestion.
I am writing a C program consisting of, among the other things, two threads, one sending a message and the other checking the reply to the message. I would like that the thread sending the message stop till the receiving thread turn to true a bool variable suggesting that requests contained in the sending message has been satisfied.
I wrote a code of this type.
For the sending thread:

```
  executed = false;
  function_to_send_the_message();
  while(!executed);
```

For the receiving thread:

```
msg = function_to_receive_the_message();

if(msg->good){
    status = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    assert(status == 0);
    executed = true;
    printf("Executed order!\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    assert(status == 0);
 }
```

The mutex is a global variable.
This is a simplified code, so don't look at some weird statements.
The point is that the sending thread is blocked in the while loop and doesn't go ahead. I don't know if and how I have to put a mutex also in the while loop. 
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: you probably want condition variables not mutexes

Comment: All accesses to shared state (such as global variable `executed`; both reads and writes) must be synchronized, such as by protecting them with a mutex.  You only go halfway there.  Also, making a thread wait until some condition is satisfied is the express purpose of condition variables.

Comment: If you **really** want to do busy-waiting, why not use spinlocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sending thread, the loop

```
while(!executed);
```

gets optimized by the compiler to something like

```
some_register = !executed;
while(some_register);
```

since as far as it can tell, the value of `executed` can't change between tests of the loop condition (the loop body is empty, after all).

The usually suggested way to solve this is by having a mutex protect each read/write to this variable, like this:

```
temp = true;
while(temp){
  mutex_lock(m);
  temp = !executed;
  mutex_unlock(m);
}
```

or even better for this case, a condition variable. These constructs cause "memory barriers", which simply put means that variables that were loaded into registers before accessing a mutex will be assumed stale and reloaded after using it.

Another approach that is often misused but can be a correct approach in certain cases is to declare `executed` as `volatile`. This causes every read/rite *of only this variable* to go all the way to the memory and not used cached registers.

Comment: volatile and multithreading... How nice. The text is wrong on substance. *to go all the way to the memory and not used cached registers* - just plain wrong.

Comment: @SergeyA Please, enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

I would be hugely tempted to put the condition var, (or event/semaphore synchro object), in the message itself.  The producer sends the message and waits on the synchro, the consumer processes it and signals the synchro.

That is more flexible, (multiple producers can easily and safely 'use' the consumer, assuming your message queue/whatever is multiple-producer safe), and gets rid of the nasty global.

'while(!executed);' polling is just terrible.  A waste of CPU cycles and memory-bandwidth.  Super-lame:(   Stil, in an attempt to actually answer the question, even though it's a really bad design - use an atomic int/bool.  Look to your OS to find out what instructions to use - C itself is no help:(

Comment: *C itself is no help*  - not true. `atomic_int` is to rescue.